# How to add angular routing between two projects

Tags: angular, angular-routing

We have two projects consider as A and B. where A is main project which contains few links which redirects to Project B for now we have added external links to open project B within same environment. but now can we want to add angular routing is it possible

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What did you try? Links should help you with routing, what more do you need?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu how to add routing in project b to open project A components

Comment: A potential solution for you might be to use libraries: https://angular.io/guide/libraries

Comment: Just use a link. Is this not working for you? `<a href="base.url.here/projectB/route1?queryParam1=x">Go to Project B</a>`

Comment: let's say you want to open Project B when you vist ```/project_b```. You want angular routing to handle it? correct? I don't think there is any way to tell angular router to load different javascript (angular project) from network. This feature exits but only for lazy loaded component not for whole project.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu there are many places where i need to update the link so if it is routing i can do it in single place